# Type casting in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

It is defined in the type promotion rule for java that long data can be casted into float data type. how it is possible??

for example :

```
 class casting{

    void show(float a){
   System.out.println("float");
   }


 public static void main(String args[]){
   casting obj = new casting();
  obj.show(10l);
  }

}
```

but here output is flaot 
How the long data which is 8 byte are converted into float data(4 byte)?

Comment: What is your question. There is no "?" mark in your posting.

Comment: my question is how this conversion is possible. in float type date(4 byte) long data(8 byte) is stored how..??

Comment: This [reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1293836/1060037) should tell you why.

Comment: can you help yourself to follow java naming conventions? Use pascal case while writing class name and use camel case while writing method names.

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293819/why-does-java-implicitly-without-cast-convert-a-long-to-a-float
this should make it clear.

Comment: It's possible because floating-point types are inherently inexact, and Java doesn't mind losing the precise value when you do that type of conversion. The conversion preserves the magnitude, however.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your program as follows. long is a 64bit signed datatype and the maximum value is 9223372036854775807l.    when you convert that to float, it prints as 9.223372E18.  float is 32 bit single precision data type.  Hope this helps

```
public class casting {

    void show(float a) {
        System.out.println("float is " + a);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        casting obj = new casting();
        obj.show(9223372036854775807l);
    }

}
```