# information loss from long to float in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, primitive

if you call the following method of Java

```
void processIt(long a) {
  float b = a;  /*do I have loss here*/
}
```

do I have information loss when I assign the long variable to the float variable?

The Java language Specification says that the *float* type is a supertype of *long*.

Comment: You will get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293819/why-does-java-implicitly-without-cast-convert-a-long-to-a-float

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Answer (score 6):

> Do I have information loss when I assign the long variable to the float variable?

Potentially, yes. That should be fairly clear from the fact that `long` has 64 bits of information, whereas `float` has only 32.

More specifically, as `float` values get bigger, the gap between successive values becomes more than 1 - whereas with `long`, the gap between successive values is *always* 1.

As an example:

```
long x = 100000000L;
float f1 = (float) x;
float f2 = (float) (x + 1);
System.out.println(f1 == f2); // true
```

In other words, two *different* `long` values have the same nearest representation in `float`.

This isn't just true of `float` though - it can happen with `double` too. In that case the numbers have to be bigger (as `double` has more precision) but it's still potentially lossy.

Again, it's reasonably easy to see that it *has* to be lossy - even though both `long` and `double` are represented in 64 bits, there are obviously `double` values which can't be represented as `long` values (trivially, 0.5 is one such) which means there must be some `long` values which aren't exactly representable as `double` values.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible: if only for the reason that `float` has too few (typically 6-7) significant digits to deal with all possible numbers that `long` can represent (19 significant digits). This is in part due to the fact that `float` has only 32 bits of storage, and `long` has 64 (the other part is float's storage format <sup>†</sup> ). As [per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, **may result in loss of precision** - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

By example:

```
long i = 1000000001; // 10 significant digits
float f = i;
System.out.printf(" %d %n %.1f", i, f);
```

This prints (with the difference highlighted):

```
 1000000001
 1000000000.0
          ~  ← lost the number 1
```

It is worth noting this is also the case with `int` to `float` and `long` to `double` (as per that quote). In fact the only integer → floating point conversion that won't lose precision is `int` to `double`.

~~~~~~

<sup>†</sup> I say *in part* as this is also true for `int` widening to `float` which can also lose precision, despite both `int` and `float` having 32-bits. The same sample above but with `int i` has the same result as printed. This is unsurprising once you consider the way that `float` is structured; it uses some of the 32-bits to store the mantissa, or significand, so cannot represent all integer numbers in the same range as that of `int`.

Comment: @user3477487. It is also worth reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long g = 2;
    g <<= 48;
    g++;

    System.out.println(g);
    float f = (float) g;
    System.out.println(f);
    long a = (long) f;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

... prints...

```
562949953421313
5.6294995E14
562949953421312
```