# widening type conversions in Java

Tags: java, casting

Herbert Schild states in *Java A Beginner's Guide*:

> an automatic type conversion will take place if (a) the two types are compatible and (b) **the destination type is larger then the source type**

But: He then casts a `long` into a `double` so (b) is violated as a 64-bit integer is obviously bigger than a 32-bit type. This is a little confusing and counterintuitive at first.

Shouldn't the condition refined to

> **the destination type is larger or smaller then the source type** given that such a conversion then takes only place if no data is lost as the destination type is sufficiently big enough to hold the data of the source type?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: note a cast is not an automatic conversion. also please show the code you're talking about.

Comment: where is the difference: implitcit- / explicitness? Regarding the code, it was more like a general question rather than something that has to do with actual code.

Comment: explicit cast != automatic conversion and double == 64 bits (but the mantissa is only 52.)

Comment: explicit cast : `double a = (double) 32L;` implicit conversion : `char c = 'a'; int a = c;`

Answer (score 1):

Both `double` and `long` are 64-bit. However, assigning a 64-bit integer to a double may cause precision loss, which is why an explicit cast is required. Therefore there's no automatic type conversion taking place in this case.

Comment: thx. I did for some reason assume that double is 32-bit. Mixed it up with float somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Actually double is also 64 bits in size.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Such a conversion is called widening conversion which can lead to loss of precision but is allowed.

See the accepted answer for a similar question

[Why does Java implicitly (without cast) convert a `long` to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293819/why-does-java-implicitly-without-cast-convert-a-long-to-a-float)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

> **A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long
>   value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result
>   may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this
>   case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded
>   version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode**
>
> **long**: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The
>   signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1.
>   In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an
>   unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum
>   value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values
>   wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods
>   like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic
>   operations for unsigned long.
>
> **double**: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>   discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and
>   Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values,
>   this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above,
>   this data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>   currency.