# Why is the order of downcasting in Java float <- long?

Tags: java, casting

My textbook says this:

> Converting from a larger type to a smaller type is called a down cast,
> also known as range narrowing.
>
> Byte <-  short <-  int <- **float <-
> long** <-  double

Why is long higher than float on the downcasting/narrowing list?

Isn't the range of values represented by a float much wider than the range represented by a long?

E.g., when casting types (assuming f represents a float and l represents a long), you can do do f = l, but this requires an explicit cast: l = (long) f. Doesn't this show that a float should be higher than a long on the downcasting list?

Comment: The range is wider, but the precision is lower.

Comment: [Why does Java implicitly (without cast) convert a `long` to a `float`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293819/why-does-java-implicitly-without-cast-convert-a-long-to-a-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A  `long` and a `double` are both 64 bits whereas a `float` is only a 32 bit data type. Thus it takes a downcast to turn the `long`'s 64 bit number into a 32 bit.

When programming, `float` has a wider range of number, but the `long` uses its 64 bits to create a more precise number. This is the reason you use `float` when you need to save space on a less precise number, but for something where precision is important (i.e., currency, scientific calculations, etc) a `long` is what you should be using.

If you're curious you can check out the Java Doc's [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)