# Why is it that I can declare a numerical variable as a double but still use .nextInt()?

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types

Okay, I'm new to coding so I am unfamiliar with everything. Here's my question:

Why is it that .nextInt(); will process a double even though the name is .nextInt();?

```
double max = scan.nextInt();
```

This works, but why?

Comment: `scan.nextInt()` is an `int`; `int` can be widened to `double`.

Comment: [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) - *`int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you peek into the [java-doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) you'll actually see that [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) returns `int` as the method name suggests.

In your specific example, the value returned from [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) is *widened* to a `double` as every `int` can fit into a `double` type.

Answer (score 0):

The things after the period (`.nextInt()`) are called methods or functions.

Now to your actual question:

The method `.nextInt()` will return an integer, which will then be converted internally to a `double`, since every `int` is also a `double` if you ask for it explicitly (by saying `double max=`)

Also see: [Why does Java implicitly (without cast) convert a `long` to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293819/why-does-java-implicitly-without-cast-convert-a-long-to-a-float)

Answer (score -1):

As others have indicated, this is an example of an [implicit cast](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0080__Type-Casting/Implicitandexplicitcasting.htm) - you can assign an `int` to a `double` and it'll automatically be typecast (have the type changed) for you.

The basic idea here is that there's not really any serious harm in assigning an `int` to a `double` (other than consuming marginally more memory).

Note that the converse is *not* true - there *could* be serous harm in casting a `double` to `int`, so there is no implicit cast from `double` to `int`.